# Reset a @HTML.DropDownList & Table on button click without JavaScript or JQuery

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

Hi I need some help as I am new to MVC. I have a Drop Down List that is being populated with values from the config. I am going to use this drop down to pass a value when hitting submit to run a Query and bring back data into a table.

Where I need help:

If a user wants to reset the drop down back to "Choose Your Value" and clear the table of the data for in prep to run a new query, I want them to be able to click the "Clear" button and be able to do so.

I searched a lot and learned a lot about JavaScript ways of doing this, but I would like to use .NET and MVC.

Here is my Drop Down code:

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }
 @Html.DropDownList("YourElementName", 
 (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DropdownVals, "--Choose Your Value--", 
 new {

        //size = "5",
        style = "width: 600px"

        }
```

I have a button like this:

```
<input id="Button2" type="button" value="Clear" />
```

Can the button call some code in the controller that will clear both the list and table data?

Please explain in detail if you have time.

Any help is much appreciated.

Controller as it is right now:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        string[] values = (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DropdownValues"]).Split(',').Select(sValue => sValue.Trim()).ToArray();
        List<SelectListItem> dropDowns = new List<SelectListItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            dropDowns.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = values[i], Value = values[i] });
        }
        ViewBag.DropdownVals = dropDowns;


        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Can post the controller method for loading the page and the method to which you submit and get the data?

Comment: I mean not wanting to use `jquery` is understandable but why don't you want to use javascript? For clearing, you'd have to do a page refresh

Comment: @adiga I updated question with controller code. I wouldn't mind Javascript but every example I looked at it had to go through hoops to get the end result. I just wanted something simple and couldn't find anything.

Comment: you can try this: `<input id="Button2" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="window.location.reload()" /> `. It will simply reload the page.

Comment: @adiga That worked perfectly. Its a simple app I want to keep it simple. Thanks, can you answer my question and I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply reload the page, which will set the dropdown and the page to default.

```
<input id="Button2" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="window.location.reload()" />
```

Again, this also depends on how you are fetching the data. If it is a `Get` request with `dropdown` value in the query string, then this wouldn't work.

You'd have to do:

```
<input id="Button2" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "ControllerName")'" />
```

Comment: How does this answer the question - OP has specifically stated _without JavaScript or JQuery_ (`onclick` **IS** javascript)

Comment: @StephenMuecke One of my comments says that I wouldn't mind Javascript, but didn't want something complicated.

Comment: @Abdul, That is not what you question says (we answer the question, not comments). And if you are going to use javascript, then use [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) - we are in the 21st century now :) - `$(yourButton).click(function() { ...`

Answer (score 1):

The natural way to do something like that is using client side code, you don't need something in the server to do this.

Using server side code, is an overkill, but the simple way is to reload the same page (where the dropdownlist is set by default without a selected item).

**For a simple javascript way, and not reloading the page:**

```
<input id="Button2" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="document.getElementById('YourElementID').value=''" />
```

Comment: You are right, did't notice something was displayed.